# Meaning of Evenly distributed

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, ambiguity

What is the exact meaning of *evenly* in phrases such as:

> Users are evenly distributed between these types

or

> Users were split roughly evenly among these categories

does it mean *on the same level*?

Comment: Do you have a dictionary? Look up *evenly*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you did a survey asking 50 users to rate the usability of a website.

If there were 40 men and 10 women who took your survey, then the respondents were **not** evenly distributed according to gender. If 35 people were under the age of 25, and only 5 were over the age of 50, then your sample was **not** evenly distributed by age.

To get a more evenly distributed sample, you'd need to have closer to a 50/50 mix by gender, and a relatively even number of twenty-, thirty-, forty-, and fifty-somethings.

It should be noted that [distributions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution) are used commonly in statistics, and using the term *evenly distributed* is going to mean something [very specific](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)) to a statistician. If you're not sure your data is truly evenly distributed, it might be better to stick with a less formal term for it.

Answer (score 2):

It means *equally*, indicating that each distribution or category has (roughly) the same number of users.